# C# code very slow with debugger attached; MemoryMappedFile's fault?

Tags: c#, performance, debugging, .net-4.0, memory-mapped-files

I have a client/server app.  The server component runs, uses WCF in a 'remoting' fashion (binary formatter, session objects).

If I start the server component and launch the client, the first task the server does completes in <0.5sec.

If I start the server component with VS debugger attached, and then launch the client, the task takes upwards of 20sec to complete.

There are no code changes - no conditional compilation changes.  The same occurs whether I have the server component compiled and running in 32-bit, 64-bit, with the VS hosting process, without the VS hosting process, or any combination of those things.

**Possibly important**: If I use the VS.NET *profiler* (sampling mode), then the app runs as quick as if there were no debugger attached.  So I can't diagnose it that way.  Just checked, instrumentation mode also runs quickly.  Same for the concurrency profiling mode, works quickly.

Key data:

- The app uses fairly heavy multithreading (40 threads in the standard thread pool).  Creating the threads happens quickly regardless and is not a slow point.  There are many locks, `WaitHandle`s and `Monitor` patterns
- The app raises no exceptions at all.
- The app creates no console output.
- The app is entirely managed code.
- The app does map a few files on disk to a MemoryMappedFile: 1x750MB and 12x8MB and a few smaller ones

Measured performance:

- CPU use is minimal in both cases; when debugger is attached, CPU sits at <1%
- Memory use is minimal in both cases; maybe 50 or 60MB in both cases
- There are plenty of page faults happening (ref MMF), however they happen more slowly when the debugger is attached
- If the VS hosting process is not used, or basically the 'remote debugging monitor' comes into play, then *that* uses a decent amount CPU and creates a good number of page faults.  But that's not the only time the problem is occurring
- The performance difference is seen regardless of how the client is run.  The only variable being changed is the server component being run via 'Start with debugging' vs launched from Explorer.

My ideas:

- WCF slow when debugged?
- MemoryMappedFiles slow when debugged?
- 40 threads used - slow to debug?  Perhaps Monitors/locks notify debugger?  Thread scheduling becomes strange/context switches very infrequent?
- Cosmic background radiation granting intelligence and cruel sense of humour to VS

All seem stupidly unlikely.

So, my questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. If #1 unknown, how can I diagnose / find out?

Comment: Have you enabled 1st-chance exception catch? You can also try to Enable .NET Server Source Stepping to catch a maximum of underlying "hidden" exceptions in debug mode, notably the (de)serlization ones. Also, what about traces (outputdebugstring or other)?

Comment: Yes, no exceptions are thrown at all - all categories of exception (incl .NET) enabled for 1st chance.  There's no debug console output (that's what I meant by console output - I will edit to clarify).  I just enabled .NET Framework Source Stepping (couldn't see Server Source Stepping).. found some exceptions.  Will update momentarily

Comment: Exception from WCF: "The ' ' character, hexadecimal value 0x20, cannot be included in a name.".  I had *no idea* that exceptions could be hidden in this way: isn't an exception an exception?  Will see what I can do to resolve.  Perhaps you could post an answer so you can get some upvotes/an accept if this fixes it? :)

Comment: Are you using a conditional breakpoint? I've seen these slow down work tremendously.

Comment: @Paul - nope no breakpoints!  I think Simon is on to something, trying to fix the hidden exceptions and see if that speeds everything up.

Comment: @SimonMourier: success!  Could you post an answer so I can give you a well-deserved tick/vote?  If possible could you explain why/how exceptions can be hidden despite first-chance exceptions being turned on?  The exception: I had a custom serialisation routine, used `SerializationInfo.SetValue()` but used a name parameter that wasn't a valid XML element name.  Apparently I was using XML serialisation after all, binary not configured correctly.

Comment: Also, "NetTcpBinding uses TCP for the transport, binary for the message encoding, and SOAP 1.2 for the message version." .. well, I'm using NetTcpBinding.  Why do I have to serialise into a dictionary with valid XML names?

Comment: @PaulPhillips - You should put that in an answer, it solved my problem.

Comment: In some circumstances the level of IntelliTrace might be the culprit. We had slower SqlCommand while debugging, and decreasing the level to "IntelliTrace events only" fixed the issue, thanks to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33173014/visual-studio-2015-debugger-high-performance-impact-on-sqlcommand

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exceptions can notably impact the performance of an application. There are two types of exceptions: 1st chance exceptions (the one gracefully handled with a try/catch block), and unhandled exceptions (that will eventually crash the application).

By default, the debugger does not show 1st chance exceptions, it just shows unhandled exceptions. And by default, it also shows only exceptions occurring in your code. However, even if it does not show them, it still handles them, so its performance may be impacted (especially in load tests, or big loop runs).

To enable 1st chance exceptions display in Visual Studio, click on "Debug | Exceptions" to invoke the Exceptions dialog, and check "Thrown" on the "Common language runtime" section (you can be more specific and choose wich 1st chance exception you want to see).

To enable 1st chance exceptions display originating from anywhere in the application, not just from your code, click on "Tools | Options | Debugging | General" and disable the "Enable Just My Code" option.

And for these specific "forensics mode" cases, I also strongly recommend to enable .NET Framework Source Stepping (it requires "Enable Just My Code" to be disabled). It's very useful to understand what's going on, sometimes just looking at the call stack is very inspiring - and helpful especially in the case of cosmic radiation mixup :-)

Two related interesting articles:

- [How to debug crashes and hangs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/12/07/how-to-debug-crashes-and-hangs.aspx)
- [Configuring Visual Studio to Debug .NET Framework Source Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx)

Comment: As per my other comments, the exception was completely 'hidden', until I enabled '.NET Framework Source Stepping'.  There was an error where `SerializationInfo.SetValue()` throws an exception about the `string` parameter not being a valid XML element name, even though it would continue to work, and furthermore, I was using NetTcpBinding (i.e., binary formatter).

Comment: Most of the directions don't exist anymore on VS2019. Would love an edit on this answer :)

Comment: @Gulzar - not sure how to proceed because this kind of answer is kinda outdated when you use modern tooling but not everyone does. Plus some info are still valid. Usually, people (like you -:) look at the date and figure out it's outdated so no big deal. IMHO you should write another question or give another answer maybe.

Comment: @SimonMourier I actually only looked at the date after I tried this. Tyron's answer ended up to be the solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 11):

Since this is one of the first results when googling for this issue I would like to add my problem solution here in the hopes of saving someone 2 hours of research like in my case.

My code slowed down from 30 seconds without debugger attached to 4 minutes with debugger. because I forgot to remove a conditional breakpoint. These seem to slow down execution tremendously, so watch out for those

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes:

1. Various special kinds of breakpoints such as:

   - Conditional breakpoints
   - Memory changed breakpoints
   - Function breakpoints
2. Having the "Enable native code debugging" option checked.

   - This option makes debug runs slow as molasses.
   - This option is *not* under Tools -> Options -> Debug, (that would make too much sense,) it is under Project -> Properties -> Debug
3. Excessive use of `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write()`.

   - My benchmarks show that 1000 invocations of `Debug.WriteLine()` take only 10 milliseconds when running without debugging, but a whole 500 milliseconds when debugging. Apparently the Visual Studio Debugger, when active, intercepts DotNet debug output, and does extremely time-consuming stuff with it. (Over decades of using Microsoft products, we have come to expect nothing less from Microsoft.)
   - Replacing `Debug.WriteLine()` with kernel32.dll -> PInvoke -> `OutputDebugStringW()` does not help, because when running a DotNet application, Visual Studio completely ignores kernel32 debug output and only displays DotNet debug output, which is a completely different thing. (And I suppose that anything else would, again, make too much sense.)
4. Excessive amount of exceptions being thrown and caught, as another answer suggests.

   - Throwing an exception under DotNet is a mind-bogglingly slow operation.
   - Collecting a stack trace under DotNet is an insanely slow operation.

Comment: Indeed, writing to System.Diagnostic.Trace is extremely slow with a debugger attached, esp. if debugging remotely (e.g. into an Azure app service). To the point I actually had a vicious circle because I was logging to here every time a function was slow, hence making it even slower and causing the same tracing logic in the calling-function to log again, etc. etc. Firing it off asynchronously seems to work ok though.