# SQL Server Broker Service is slow to enqueue

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-performance, service-broker

I'm trying to figure out why the enqueuing of messages is so slow with my SSBS instance.

I'm using ado.net to connect from a C# application.  Its taking 5-6 seconds to enqueue approximately 720 messages.

I've divided up the messages into 50 message chunks, and each chunk goes on its own conversation.

I'm using the "150 trick" to ensure each conversation handle is on its on data page, to avoid hot-spotting the conversation row.  Chunks are executed in parallel, using .net TPL.

Each chunk (50 messages) acquires its own SqlConnection, has no transaction, starts a conversation (actually 150 conversations, but only uses one), sends the messages sequentially (via a foreach loop), and then ends the conversation.

SSBS services are defined with no validation or encryption.

The client app (which sends the messages) and the Sql Server instance are both housed on the same machine, and hosted on an SSD, 32 GB Ram, i7 Processor. I'm not seeing a resources maxing out during this time.

What else should I be looking at as the cause of the poor performance?

Comment: How large are your messages and why are you cutting them into chunks?

Comment: Messages are about 500 chars each. I break them into chunks to maximize the throughput when enqueuing the messages and to minimize lock contention associated with locking the conversation row when queuing a message

Comment: Don't cut up messages if you don't have a need.  Small messages are just creating more overhead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy do I feel stupid.

I spent all day trying to identify the cause of the slowness.  Turns out it was Visual Studio's Intellitrace debugger.  When I ran my code without attaching a Debugger, I have the following results:

```
[17:56:25 DBG] Creating Conversation took 0001 millisecond(s)
[17:56:25 DBG] Sending 718 message(s) to broker service message queue.  took 0208 millisecond(s)
```

Apologies and thanks to everyone who contributed on this snipe hunt.

Comment: Does the c# code raises exceptions? Usually that is the culprit, w/o exceptions the debugger has no significant impact. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7831694/105929

Comment: Intellitrace is much more than a debugger.  It's a profiler and a logger as well.  The debugger alone would have little impact as shown by OPs update.

Comment: Disabling Intellitrace had the largest impact on performance for enqueuing the messages.  Running without an attached debugger had additional, albeit less substantial, performance improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the "150" trick, so you've read the whitepaper (for others' reference, it can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576261(v=sql.100).aspx)). Another observation from that same whitepaper is that setting up conversations is somewhat expensive. Have you measured how long the conversation setup is taking (vs actually sending the messages)?

One thing that I did when I implemented SB here was I set up a table of pre-initiated conversation handles that the application can grab at run time. They live (functionally speaking) forever  If you're interested in the details, let me know and I can post it here.

Comment: Creating a conversation takes about 20ms.  sending the 50 messages (1 bucket, using 1 conversation) is about 5-6 seconds.   Messages are small (about 500 characters).

Comment: That's weird. Using the scheme I outlined above (in which the send is abstracted out through a stored procedure), I get an average of ≈ 400 μs to send a message. That's inclusive of any locking of the conversation group/handle. And my messages aren't tiny (they're an XML representation of data changes to specific tables). Are you able to run an extended events session to see what the wait types are?

Comment: Ben - THanks for the follow up.. You mentioned "extended events session to see what the wait types are".  I'm not familiar with this. Can you provide some additional information.  Thanks.

Comment: Ben - I did some research about Extended Events, what events, actions, and filters do you recommend?

Comment: I'd work with your DBA on it (if you have one), but if it were me, I'd track either the wait_info or wait_completed event filtering on something like hostname. Out of that, I'd try to get an aggregate (both count and sum of duration) of the waits by type.